# How do inset numpy array to fit in my model?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

I have created a model of `input_shape(28,28,3)` and I have a `numpy` array of data that I need to fit in the model of `shape(28500, 784)`.

Can anyone help me fit the training data into my model?

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,3)))

x_train.shape
```

**output = (28500, 784)**

Comment: What data is representing your numpy array ? Because i assume that 28x28x3 will be an image to fit into the model, 784 = 28x28, so what is 28500 representing, the number of sample ? So where are the channels  ?

Comment: @ThibaultBacqueyrisses 28500 represents number of images of size 28x28. It is black and white doodle classifier dataset. that's the problem I couldn't find channels.

Comment: If it's only black and white images, why do you need an input shape with 3 channels ?

Comment: Because i want to test the model with 3 channel images

Comment: 2 solutions so : 
- dowload an other dataset, the more accurate way in order to have good results
- Concatenate your data 3 times in order to have 3 channels

Comment: If you did it, you can now feed it directly to your model, input_shape being only the shape of one sample, and x_train is 28500 samples.

Comment: Glad to have helped you ! Can you upvote my comment if my solution worked ? Thank you !

Comment: please upvote the answer !

Answer (score 1):

```
new_train = []
nchannels = 3
for x in x_train:
  x = np.resize(x, (28, 28, nchannels))
  new_train.append(x)
new_train = np.array(new_train)
```